# Unable to use Breeze in Jasmine/Karma tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, breeze, karma-runner

It seems that I can't even get to a starting point as I try to test Breeze using Jasmine and a Karma (in Node.js) runner. VS 2013. Karma runs in its own server so I had to allow for CORS.  Regardless, the following Jasmine test does not run:

```
describe('Able to retrieve a single account record...', function() {
    var manager, acc, asyncCallComplete;

    asyncCallComplete = false;
    manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
        serviceName: 'http://localhost:35092/api/BreezeApi'
    });

    // Load filtered accounts
    runs(function() {
        breeze.EntityQuery.from('Accounts')
            .select('id, accountName')
            .where('id', '==', 2)
            .using(manager).execute()
            .then(function() {
                acc = data.result;
            asyncCallComplete = true;
            }, function (error) {
            asyncCallComplete = true;
            throw error;
        });

        waitsFor(function () {
            return asyncCallComplete != false;
        });

        expect(acc.accountName).toBe('Account Two');
    });
});
```

Simple enough, but it doesn't work.  The query neither succeeds nor fails, it just times out.  Interestingly, the browser shows that the metadata is retrieved, but there is no subsequent call to obtain the ACCOUNT record (in this case).

Comment: setting asyncCallComplete = true in the error function looks wrong!